# App Store Connect API request Sales Report

Tags: app-store-connect

App Store connect api requested sales report with curl.

Below is the request address according to the apple guide.

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [token]' 
"https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter\ 
[frequency\]=DAILY&filter\[reportDate\]=2019-02-01&filter\ 
[reportSubType\]=SUMMARY&filter\[reportType\]=SALES&filter\ 
[vendorNumber\]=86890785&filter\[version\]=1_0"
```

According to the guide, the 'users' information is normally obtained, but the sales report is garbled and the response comes.

```
 ?p?\?{~7[?.?????j???????p?????E?????q6?}?|?/???{?]???z??O?fϫ??s???<?W?????w;?ݽ??g?????t5?U????O?7?-???ۿF?W?!??\?/?l?={//??߸??\,?3=??E??/?꯯??{????v9Y????r????/????}=p?/?z{yY,W?????t??b??:?G0??M_???Ζ??F???????q?~??|??~0????ŧ?ї????i?ǭ??Ƿ??????n??0?G??????}}gN?I<
?"?ˬ???3?????y?x{???r5?߿?;s?=ڻ?R&F'????;???7?X?I?LΏ?C?1&õ?y??????????a'E?$qǯX<϶?}"wo???ų}a???Џ!?Frrv?>?1?yT?e????s?x?ReY
"?D]??ru??-?&IY?EţtR??o?O???}?meË???? ?1?0??4???K?x?*T+nu?}??S???ד?P ........skip
```

I think there are a lot of data to fetch this problem. Is there a way to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Apple guide : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is compressed in .gz format. Try to perform get with Postman and download the result in order to check it out.